# Pythonic pip freeze in Nim or how to list installed packages?

Tags: nim-lang, nimble-nim

How to `pip freeze` command looks for Nim's package manager nimble ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For freezing with nimble command :

```
nimble list --installed
```

or

```
nimble list -i
```